# Another [Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference'] in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, razor, file-upload

I tried to have a file upload into another folder, it works fine when it directly add to the database, but if I try to use it with `MultipleDocumentCreateClass` for the stored procedure, I get this error:

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference'

Controller

```
    // GET: Activity/DocumentNew
    public ActionResult DocumentNew(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Hoạt_động hoạt_động = db.Hoạt_động.Find(id); ;
        ViewBag.act = hoạt_động;

        if (hoạt_động == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        MultipleDocumentCreateClass mtd = new MultipleDocumentCreateClass();
        mtd.Mã_Hoạt_động = hoạt_động.Mã_Hoạt_động;
        Dropdownlist2();
        return View(mtd);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DocumentNew([Bind(Include = "Mã_Hoạt_động, Tên, Loại,Thông_tin, Nội_dung")]MultipleDocumentCreateClass mt)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[0];

                if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

                    //Save into folder
                    file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/App_Data/Video/" + fileName));
                    mt.Nội_dung = "~/App_Data/Video/" + fileName;
                    mt.Tên = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FileName);
                }

                db.MultipleDocCr(mt.Mã_Hoạt_động, mt.Tên, mt.Loại, mt.Thông_tin, mt.Nội_dung);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }

        return View(mt);
    }
```

**MultipleDocumentUseClass**:

```
public class MultipleDocumentCreateClass
{
    public Nullable<int> Mã_Hoạt_động { get; set; }
    public string Tên { get; set; }
    public string Loại { get; set; }
    public string Thông_tin { get; set; }
    public string Nội_dung { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Hoạt động: @Model.Mã_Hoạt_động</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Mã_Hoạt_động, new { value = ViewBag.act.Mã_Hoạt_động })

        <dt>
            Hoạt động:
            @ViewBag.act.Tên
        </dt>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Loại, "Thể loại", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Loại, new SelectList(ViewBag.doc, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Loại, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Thông_tin, "Thông tin", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Thông_tin, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Thông_tin, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nội_dung, "Chọn File", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nội_dung, new { htmlAttributes = new { Type = "file" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nội_dung, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Lưu" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

The error points to this line

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Mã_Hoạt_động, new { value = ViewBag.act.Mã_Hoạt_động })
```

but when I add value manually without uploading, it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer at the `@using (Html.BeginForm())` in View

Change it into this `@using (Html.BeginForm("DocumentNew", "Activity", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))`